# SQL Server Login Error when connecting to server with multiple instances

Tags: sql-server, instances

I have a new dedicated SQL Server with 3 different instances installed.

- SQL Server 2008 STANDARD
- SQL Server 2008 EXPRESS R2
- SQL Server 2012 EXPRESS

I am able to bring up all three in SSMS and can attach databases etc no problems.

I am able to connect to each of the different instances from different remote web sites (as I have defined different ports for each instance).

However, no matter which user I try and connect with its giving me this error.

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'USERNAME_HERE'.

The last 6 hours, I have checked absolutely everything including trying different usernames, simple usernames and passwords, verifying firewalls, changing ports, switching each data base on one at a  time etc etc...a long list of things.

So is definitely not a username and password issue and I am stumped now as to what it can possibly be.

Could it be something to do with actual NT permissions?

PLEASE HELP ME!!! I AM GOING INSANE!!!

Comment: Why are you using `ODBC` to connect to SQL Server? I'd recommend using the **native** SQL Client

Comment: You need to have a **login** (server-level entity) on each of those instances for your user, and you'll need to create **users** in the databases on each instance where that user should be able to connect to ....

Comment: Because we have been using ODBC the last 12 years?

Comment: Okay...I have already created the user in the database instance where it should connect to. If I turn that instance off I get the error saying server does not exist. If I turn it back on again, I get the login failed error. What is a "server level entity"?

Comment: What's your connection string?

Comment: You can create a user at the SERVERNAME-Security-Logins level in the management console. That user can be mapped to all DB's in the User Mapping section. This is the easiest way to get up and running.

Comment: As mentioned by @marc_s, `LOGIN`s are to connect to the **server**, `USER`s are to interact with a **database**. Creating users to your database won't implicitly allow you to connect. You can run `CREATE LOGIN <login_name>` while connected to the server to create a new login, and then create a user using `CREATE USER <user_name> FOR LOGIN <login_name>`